# Canne / nourriture en canne

Tags: sens, définition

On emploie le mot *canne* à Montréal dans le sens de [*conserve*](https://www.google.com/search?q=canne%20nourriture&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwi009GlxI_3AhXXgXIEHVKdDVIQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=canne%20nou&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQARgBMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBggAEAUQHjIGCAAQBRAeMgYIABAIEB4yBggAEAgQHjIGCAAQCBAeMgQIABAYOgcIIxDvAxAnOgQIABBDOggIABCABBCxAzoHCAAQsQMQQ1CjDljGKmCWP2gAcAB4AIABVIgB2gKSAQE1mAEAoAEBqgELZ3dzLXdpei1pbWfAAQE&sclient=img&ei=0vdVYrSiEdeDytMP0rq2kAU&bih=927&biw=1920&client=firefox-b-d).

Pourtant, je ne trouve cette signification dans aucun dictionnaire, même pas dans *Antidote* ou [*Usito*](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/canne). Pourquoi ce mot ne figure-t-il pas dans les dictionnaires canadiens ?

Comment: Bien présent dans le [wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/canne#Nom_commun) :)

Answer (score 6):

Parce que personne n'a encore pensé à l'y mettre.

Ce [*canne*](https://www.dufrancaisaufrancais.com/articles/la-canne-une-conserve-franglaise/) est essentiellement le mot anglais (*[can](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/can)*) adapté à la graphie française, ce qui est bien sûr facilité par l'existence d'un homophone et homographe parfait.

Answer (score 2):

On le trouve rarement dans les dictionnaires en ligne d'aujourd'hui ; en [commentaire](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/50108/canne-nourriture-en-canne#comment103611_50108) on a identifié le [*Wiktionnaire*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/canne#Nom_commun). On le trouve aussi au *GPFC* :

[image]

<sup>[*Glossaire du parler français au Canada*](http://bibnum2.banq.qc.ca/bna/numtxt/179630.pdf), Société du parler français au Canada. 1930</sup>

---

*Plus*. On trouvera aussi ici et là pour le Canada le verbe [*(en)canner*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/encanner) (mettre en canne), ainsi que le [*cannage*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/cannage) (l'action d'*encanner* ou son résultat : les conserves.). Ceci rappelle aussi d'autres termes un peu similaires qu'on peut entendre dont la [*canisse*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/canisse#Nom_commun_2), voire la *canistre*, peut-être des réfections d'emplois en vieux français avec l'anglais *canister* au Québec pour un contenant comme le *bidon*, mais j'accepte la *canisse* à l'oral aussi comme une petite boîte de conserve dans un registre très familier. Au-delà du GPFC, j'accepte non seulement *acheter des tomates en canne* mais aussi « des cannes de tomates » (je suis Montréalais) dans ce genre de parler populaire.

---

Il y a bien des termes, des tournures et des emprunts qui ne sont pas documentées au lexique ou qui le sont davantage dans des œuvres spécialisées. Le *GPFC* peut être utile mais comme son contenu a près de 100 ans il faut valider si ce qu'il identifie est toujours courant ou non.

Comment: On dit aussi _canner_ (caané) pour mettre en boîte dans le sens d'annuler au figuré.

Comment: C'est très intéresant de voir que ce mot pourrait avoir des racines doubles. Autrement dit, ce n' pas un simple calque...

Comment: Merci. On dit aussi _canistre_ en [russe](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0), certains mots sont venus du français comme _balcon_, _divan_, mais on prononce toutes les lettres, celles à la fin aussi.